# Ubuntu 18.04 boot error in VMware workstation 12 player

Tags: networking, display-resolution, vmware

I get the following error during ubuntu 18.04 starting through vmware workstation 12 player :

> [FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
>   See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
>   [ OK ] Stopped Network Name Resolution

Earlier, this was working fine. WMware or Ubuntu 18.04 may have been corrupted while installation of some other files.

Comment: Did you run `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service`?

Comment: no  how and where i will run this command

Comment: from which prompt i will run this command i cannot loginto ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+F1 show you a tty?

Comment: my system is not dual boot system. i accessed ubuntu 18.04 from vmplayer12 within windows10. i tried ctrl+alt+f1    it does not open any new terminal

Comment: also during restart(by clicking restart guest) i am getting the  following:                                                
 The request to Reset this virtual machine failed because the corresponding VMware Tools script did not run successfully. If you have configured a custom reset script in this virtual machine, make sure that it contains no errors. Attempting the operation again will ignore the script failure. You can also submit a support request to report this issue.

Comment: after reading some other post in this forum, i give restart, click the mouse in virtual box area and hold shift key down.                                                        then i get command prompt. there i did not find failsafe mode.                           i go to root shell prompt. then run chmod 755 /etc/.*( after reading some other post).                                                                                                                
 still the problem persists. anyone can help to resolve. at least i can go to command terminal now but what to do now

Comment: @guillermo chamorro i give command systemctl status systemd-resolved.service.  now after restart the error vanishes, all are ok. but will it time to kick off ubuntu 18.04. all are showing now ok in green

Comment: Sorry but I think I can't help you. Nonetheless, I'm not sure that changing permissions in `/etc` is a good idea... it can wreck your system. Where did you find this?

Comment: @guillermo chamorro  i give your command systemctl status systemd-resolved.service. error vanishes, but after restart the ubuntu is ok but i cannot get userid password prompt. what to do now,   i think it is space issue, i allocated 60gb and 57 gb consumed, should i increase space to 80 gb from 60 gb in vmplayer manger and give a restart. or is it not advisable to increase the GB space from vm player manager

Comment: i increased the space to 70 gb from 60 gb. but ubuntu did not start at all though there was no error. anybody can you help please.

Comment: @guillermo chamorro thanks you very much for your help.  i first run systemctl status systemd-resolved.service.    then i have cleared the space. my ubutu space was 100% full that is why i could not start ubuntu 18.04. now after clearing spacs i can login. thanks a lot boss for your help